# Artisan::call('db:seed') not work in production

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

My app is Laravel 5.1 and artisan call method work fine in local. But not work in production.

```
Artisan::call('db:seed', [
      '--class'   => 'ResetSeeder',
      '--force'   => true
]);
```

This is my code in controller. when i var_dump this code in local and production; return zero (0). But local is execute and production not_execute.

My database settings is perfect. All system methods work fine. Only Artisan::call() is not working.

NOTE: when i call "php artisan db:seed --class=ResetSeeder --force" command on console. This command work fine in console too.

Thank you so much for help me and sorry my English.

Comment: I'm debug the code. Artisan::call() is work. But `DB::table('banner_boxed')->insertGetId($data);` code in my seeder, return id but not insert the data.

Comment: And my table AUTO_INCREMENT id is increasing but not insert any data

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. It's my carelessness. missing `DB::commit()`